# C Program, linker error

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
   print("Merry Christmas and happy holidays!");
   return 0;
}
```

Can someone please run this on your system and check back why?

It says, `linker error` `print is not defined`.

Comment: Use `printf`, not `print`. And Merry Christmas! :)

Comment: glad you guys got it :-) @mbratch and TheBeacon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no `print` function in standard C. The function you are looking for is `printf` (**f** here is short for **formatted**.

```
printf("Merry Christmas and happy holidays!");
```

Comment: @Aniket Merry Christmas to you. I just got the *Ho Ho Ho* hat from this post.

Comment: I got it too.. and wore it!

Answer (score 2):

It is not `print`, it is called `printf` function. There is nothing call `print` in C .standard

Comment: Merry Christmas. I didn't see your reputations first. After answering the question, then I looked at your reputation, then I came to know, you just wanted to wish...Merry Christmas once again....

Answer (score 0):

linker errors are due to the call of functions that are not defined or due to wrong way of call of a function.

In your program function `print()` does not exist anywhere as a user defined function nor does it exist in the header 'stdio.h' that you included.

To print a line in C you need to use `printf()` statement and not `print()` as in your program.